# Joining two arrays/lists of different lengths and setting the correct axis for joining

Tags: python, numpy, append

The lists that I would like to join are two dates lists on which has one more value than the other.

```
   dates2008 = [2008-12-29 00:00:00 2008-12-30 00:00:00 2008-12-31 00:00:00]
   dates2009 = [2009-01-01 00:00:00 2009-01-02 00:00:00]
```

I think this can be done by numpy append:

```
   a = np.array(dates2008)
   b = np.array(dates2009)
   mergedlist = np.append(a, b)
```

I get the new list of dates joined in sequence however this changes the dimension which I want to keep the same and I don't know which axis to join them on. Could someone help please.

Comment: Please try to make more clear what you are trying to achieve / what result you would like to see.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly what you want, you can use `numpy.hstack()` in order to merge those two `numpy.ndarray`:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime

dates2008 = [datetime.datetime(2008, 12, i) for i in range(29,32)]
dates2009 = [datetime.datetime(2009, 1, i) for i in range(1,3)]
a = np.array(dates2008)
b= np.array(dates2009)

merged = np.hstack((a,b))

## output ##

print "a = {0}".format(a)
print "b = {0}".format(b)
print "merged = {0}".format(merged)
```

Which will output:

```
a = [datetime.datetime(2008, 12, 29, 0, 0)
 datetime.datetime(2008, 12, 30, 0, 0)
 datetime.datetime(2008, 12, 31, 0, 0)]
b = [datetime.datetime(2009, 1, 1, 0, 0) datetime.datetime(2009, 1, 2, 0, 0)]
merged = [datetime.datetime(2008, 12, 29, 0, 0)
 datetime.datetime(2008, 12, 30, 0, 0)
 datetime.datetime(2008, 12, 31, 0, 0) datetime.datetime(2009, 1, 1, 0, 0)
 datetime.datetime(2009, 1, 2, 0, 0)]
```